# American Engish expressions

Tags: expressions

Why does the word "it" mean "everything", "all" or "whole" in these expressions?:

> 1.-That's **it**!
>
> 2.-‘Dr Kernohan said: ‘If this fails we're going to have to do some hard thinking, and one option is just to move on and say, that's **it**.’’
>
> 3.-‘If you have so many complaints against your name then that's **it**.’
>
> 4.-‘I might have a cuppa and a biscuit but that's **it** until my evening meal, and by then I'm past it and don't want anything.’

Why does this pronoun work as a noun in these expressions and other else?

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think it refers to "everything". And the answer for your question is it's [idiomatic](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/that-s-it)

Comment: We need more context. *That's it* can be used in many, many circumstances; in what circumstances do you believe it means "all" or "everything"? Aside from that, *it* is a pronoun: it always acts as a noun phrase, referring to some previously identified entity.

Comment: Do you have a context? That's it = And that's all. In most cases.

Comment: OK. I will add some examples from an e-English dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all your sentences, *it* is used to mean "enough for the purpose".

When an American says "That's it" in anger, he means that his patience is exhausted and whatever has just happened is sufficient to justify whatever extreme action he now proposes.  An irate parent might say to an errant child, "That's it.  I have had it.  Go to your room."

If an American says, "I will have a cup of coffee but that's it", he means a cup of coffee is all he will have, a cup of coffee is enough.

But no American would say "cuppa"; the vast majority don't even know what the word means.  And to an American, a biscuit is a small bun, leavened with sodium bicarbonate instead of yeast and typically served with breakfast, especially a breakfast of greasy foods like pork, where its alkaline taste offsets the oils of the meat.  When a Brit says "a cuppa and a biscuit", the biscuit is the small, sweet, crunchy, flat pastry that an American calls a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

from Cambridge Oxford Dictionary

> that's it ​
>
> - used to say that something has ended: Well, that's it,
>     we're done - we can go home now. That's it! I'm not listening to any
>     more of your lies.
> - used to say that something is correct: You
>     switch the computer on at the back. That's it.